# How can I get cURL to work from Windows command line?

Tags: windows, curl

I have downloaded cURL for Windows from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). I selected the `Win64 - Generic` version without `SSL`. I try to run `curl https://www.google.com` from the command line and I get the following error: `curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`.

Okay! Next, I decide to download the version with `SSL` and install that. I try to run the same command as above and I get following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate
Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you
can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

What should I do next?

Comment: If you want to use curl from windows command prompt follow this [tutorial](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2015/02/install-and-configure-curl-on-windows.html). It provides useful information about installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve the problem.

I got the Bundle of CA root certificates that Mozilla uses from [here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/source/browse/mingw/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt?r=9d3c9d917f5d7790fbb0309ebbe0303960ec8a64). I copied the data from the page and saved it in a new file called `curl-ca-bundle.crt` in the folder where the `curl.exe` file was. That solved the problem.

Of course, these instructions are also found on the cURL [documentation page for SSL certificates](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html), precisely instructions 4 and 5.

Hope that helps.